# what is the most lightweight oracle version?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i want to install oracle 11g on a very weak computer for learning.
what is the most lightweight oracle version ?
is it the express edition ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it will depend on the sorts of things you are wanting to learn.

I've been using [Oracle Database 10g Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html) as a datastore for personal/learning software development projects. From Oracle's website:

> Oracle Database 10g Express Edition (Oracle Database XE) is an entry-level, small-footprint database based on the Oracle Database 10g Release 2 code base that's free to develop, deploy, and distribute; fast to download; and simple to administer.

For what I need, I've found it quick and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle XE is the [Oracle Database 10g Express Edition](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnology%2Fxe&ei=Fe9aS-fZJ5iKngOOgr2hAg&usg=AFQjCNEpOIBPtV38qn4PFBagQdNE1QVPLQ&sig2=snbagPAcZ4AQXBQr4ZYp0A).

If you don't need any special `11g` features though, this might well be sufficient for you.

Answer (score 2):

yes oracle express edition is the one you want if you have a weaker computer. it requires 512 MB RAM to work smoothly. however, it is based on Oracle 10g release 2, so it is not quite 11g. but since you are just learning it is good. start with the tutorial here and other books in the oracle site.

http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/DBXETutorial/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle Database 11g Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html) is out.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle XE is based on 10g.  So if you want to learn Oracle 11g you should install 11g.

Answer (score 1):

As Yada says, there currently no 11g Express version and it's not due for about another year -  discussion can be found here:

http://www.infoworld.com/d/applications/oracle-says-no-cost-11g-xpress-edition-still-least-year-away-555?source=rss_infoworld_news

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) are the most lightweight version available for developers.

#### As of June, 2020, latest version of express edition is Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) Release 18.4.0.0.0 (18c):

[Latest Oracle Express Edition](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html)

#### Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) Release 11.2.0.2.0 (11gR2)

[Previous Oracle Express Edition](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-prior-releases.html)

[Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) Community Support in Database Application Development](https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/developer-tools/oracle_database_express_edition_xe/overview)

#### Oracle Database Software Downloads Enterprise Edition:

[All Editions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.